# Z-Index not working on UL LI in drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu that opens to the left but it is displaying under the content.  I tried changing the content z-index to 1 and the dropdown to 2. but it is not working.

Here is also jsFiddle sample. [https://jsfiddle.net/dgy95y8q/8/](https://jsfiddle.net/dgy95y8q/7/)

navbar CSS when not collapsed:

```
.navmenu {
    width: 0px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 180px;
    top: 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

After collapsed:

```
.navmenu.opened {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    width: 240px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The main content wrap CSS:

```
.main {
    float: left;
    width: 85%;
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `.sidebar-left` `z-index` to `2`

Comment: unbelievable! Can you explain why and how did you find out just a little bit?

Comment: I don't know why. I quickly glanced and saw that the menu you wanted on top had z-index of 0, so I bumped it to 1, didn't work. Bumped it to 2 and it worked. z-index can be any number, so I would've tried 9999999 if 2 didn't work! :D